# Background Worker Crashes Due to too Much Processing?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I've been struggling with a Background Worker for sometime, and I'm beginning to wonder if there are limits to what one can do with a bw.  I'm trying to utilize a bw to handle a TCPIP exchange while updating the UI using its `ProgressChanged` Method.  I know the UI update is ok, but my `DoWork` routine (shown below) sometimes causes the bw thread to disappear/stop working.  Has anyone else had this problem?

```
private void TCPIP_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   int a = 0;
   s.Send(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("s"));
   if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
   {
      s.Send(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("t"));
   }
   else
   {
      try
      {
         a = s.Available;
         s.Receive(bytes);
         Thread.Sleep(25);
         using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(@sbpFile.Text, 
                         FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
         {
             using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
             {
                if (a == 0)
                   Thread.Sleep(20);
                else if (a < 1023)
                {
                   bw.Write(bytes, 0, a);
                   Thread.Sleep(20);
                }
                else
                {
                   bw.Write(bytes, 0, 1024);
                   Thread.Sleep(20);
                }
             }
          }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception.", e);
       }
   }
}
```

NOTE: The only reason those Thread.Sleep() operations are in there are because they seem to be the temporary fix for having the bw not trip over itself...

Comment: Do you have any example exception messages for when it fails?

Comment: Also, what is type of object is `s`?

Comment: ...and I'd have to guess that since you're not handling exceptions on your two s.Send calls, it's probably crashing there. I'd use plain old debugging skills to walk through the code and/or trace messages with adequate error handling to actually see the errors.

Comment: You're not updating the UI from a background worker, are you?

Comment: I suggest you look into how to properly read from a Socket because you're doing some funky/buggy stuff there. There are tutorials for this.

Comment: Any exception thrown in the DoWork code will be caught and passed to the RunWorkerCompleted event handler as e.Error.  Ignoring that exception is a common way to not know why code doesn't work properly.  Remove the Sleep calls and use Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox for CLR exception to diagnose the problem.

Comment: If ever you find yourself writing `catch (Exception e)` in your code you are probably doing something wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check `Error` property on `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler. Maybe you get some exception, which in not handled by your code.

```
void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Error != null)
      Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception.", e.Error);        
   // etc
}
```